# Elastic Beanstalk : .ebextensions configuration executed and removed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am configuring CodePipeline using Elastic Beanstalk.
Elastic Beanstalk has to deploy the war file in its Tomcat's webapps folder.
But it is deploying the war file in webapps/ROOT folder.
So I have created below script *server-update.config* in *.ebextensions* folder to copy the war file into webapps folder from webapps/ROOT/.

**.ebextensions/server-update.config**

```
container_commands:
  copy_file:
    command: sudo cp /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/test/* /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/
    leader_only: true
```

Above code is executed successfully. Below is the log.

```
[2016-04-18T14:06:30.939Z] INFO  [1128]  - [Application update code-pipeline-1460988338596-MyAppBuild-2d3bd0c0-62bc-4927-bd09-b04ba81e7c03@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_SampleEB/Command copy_file] : Starting activity...
[2016-04-18T14:06:30.973Z] INFO  [1128]  - [Application update code-pipeline-1460988338596-MyAppBuild-2d3bd0c0-62bc-4927-bd09-b04ba81e7c03@15/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_SampleEB/Command copy_file] : Completed activity.
```

But ElasticBeanstalk is cleaning the tomcat webapps folder after executed .ebextensions file(while running /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/02clean.sh internally)

```
  + EB_APP_DEPLOY_BASE_DIR=/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
  + rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/sampleapp.war
```

I dont know how to configure my script to execute at last.
Please anyone help me with above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue. We needed Celery to be restarted after Django had been setup properly. We solved this very simple like this in the end.

```
files:
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_service.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        service celeryd restart
```

This is now executing after Elastic Beanstalk has worked its magic on the container.

Comment: order is important: container_commands, packages, services, files

Answer (score 0):

If you need Elastic Beanstalk to execute something post deploy you can add it to the AppDeployPostHook.  I've detailed how to do it here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36603033/3167238 which you can adapt to your specific needs.